# "Submit" instead of Sendkeys

Tags: html, vba

I have an input box that I am filling with a value in VBA, but there is no button to click to confirm the submit and I do not want to use SendKeys. How can I simulate the function of pressing "enter?" More specifically, how do I find the name of the function to call from HTML? I have HTML that looks like this but I am unsure if the file name is the function name as I am getting an automation error when I try to execScript it.

```
keydown
    document {remove} hotkeys.js?v838d760...:7
    document {remove} quickLauncherLocation.js?v838d760a4bfbbd7583a356cdf06aca2f
```

Is hotkeys() the function name and would I pass in 13?

---

Unable to copy HTML code but here is a screenshot of the hierarchy

[image: HTML Hierarchy of Input]

Comment: Can you show the HTML around it?  Is there a form to submit?

Comment: How would I check if there is a form? I've been trying to figure that out all day